# How to use the keyword 'references' in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, reference

How is the `references` keyword used when creating a table?

Let's say I want to create two tables `person` and `hobby` and I want the hobby table id to reference the id of person?

```
person table
- id
- name

hobby
- id
- person_id
- hobby_name
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Worth noting, an inline FK (`HobbyID INT REFERENCES Hobbies(ID)`) does NOT work.  This was recently reported as a bug (http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=4919), so I'm sure they'll take care of it soon.

Comment: The naming of the second table "hobby" might confuse future readers, because in reality two people can have the same hobby. (It violates first normal form)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Create the hobby table similarly to this:

```
CREATE TABLE hobby (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  person_id INT NOT NULL,
  hobby_name VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES person(id))
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is an example [directly from MySQL website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

```
CREATE TABLE parent (id INT NOT NULL,
                     PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE child (id INT, parent_id INT,
                    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
                    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id)
                    ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: what's the "ON DELETE CASCADE" sir ?

Comment: @sasori - it means that when you delete a record in table parent, all of the records in table child with fk references to parent will be deleted also.  this is referred to as a "Cascading Delete".

Answer (score 9):

```
CREATE TABLE person (person_id INT NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (person_id));

CREATE TABLE hobby (hobby_id INT NOT NULL, person_id INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(hobby_id),
FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES person(person_id));
```

The references keyword is used to define which table and column is used in a foreign key relationship. This means that a record in the `hobby` table must have a `person_id` that exists in the `person` table or else at the time of insert you will receive an error that the key does not exist.

To answer your question above about what `ON DELETE CASCADE` does, it allows you to delete a parent key record (in `person` table) and it's corresponding children records (in `hobby` table) without having to delete all the children records first.

To clarify, if you have children records attached to a primary key entry and you attempt to delete the primary key entry like:

```
DELETE FROM person where person_id = 1;
```

without having the `DELETE ON CASCADE`, you would receive an error if any records in hobby had person_id's of 1.  You would have delete all of those records first before doing the delete above.  With `DELETE ON CASCADE` used, the above delete would succeed and automatically delete any and all records from table hobby table linked to the `person_id` being deleted from the primary key table.

Answer (score 2):

Reference keyword is used actually to know where the foreign key has come.
That means which is the table name and what is the name of this in that table.

I say this is correct :

```
CREATE TABLE person (person_id INT NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (person_id));

CREATE TABLE hobby (hobby_id INT NOT NULL, person_id INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(hobby_id),
FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES person(person_id));
```

Then, look at this line :

```
FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES person(person_id));
```

Here `person_id` is the foreign key and it has come from `person` table and in that table it's name is `person_id`...
That's it.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of how you can use it.

```
create table hobby(id int references person(id),person_id int,hobby_varchar(20), primary key(id));
```

For what it means, `references` allows us to to specify the target table column to which a foreign key refers.