# activerecord relations rails confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to create a database for drinks.

Each drink has many ingredients, and ingredients have many doses.

So, a ingredient belongs to a dose and a dose belongs to cocktail.

But once I delete a drink I want to remove the associated doses but not the ingredient because that can be used in other drinks.

Currently I'm thinking about structuring my database like this.

```
rails g model drink name:string dose_id:references
rails g model dose cl:string ingredient_id:references
rails g model ingredient name:string
```

Questions:

1) Would this suit my needs or am I missing out on something?

2) Do I need a relation between cocktail and ingredient or is this done through dose? If yes/no, why?

3) Does this :references do anything else than linking a FK to a PK?

4) Is the naming important for the :references, how does it detect the table to link to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read more about references and migrations on rails guides, but here are some thoughts.

1. You seem to be missing something. You want `drink` to have many `ingredients`. Adding references to `drink` for a `dose` means a `drink` belongs to just one `dose` because it can only store one `dose_id` at a time.
2. You probably want a many to many relationship between `drink` and `ingredients`. A `drink` can have many `ingredients`. An ingredient can be part of many a `drink`. The `dose` can actually be the way to pull this off more successfully.

   ```
    rails g model drink name:string 
    rails g model dose cl:string ingredient:references drink:references
    rails g model ingredient name:string
   ```
3. It should just behave like the typical `REFERENCES` constraint in SQL. Here are some good reads on that below, but in Rails it also will add a `btree` index on the column.

   a. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK

   b. [How to use the keyword 'references' in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192280/how-to-use-the-keyword-references-in-mysql)
4. It pluralizes the model name in the references relationship when you generate the migrations.

   `rails g model dose ingredient:references` becomes like the following in the schema:

   ```
      ...
        add_index "doses", ["ingredient_id"], name: "index_doses_on_ingredient_id", using: :btree
        add_foreign_key "doses", "ingredients"
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you use MySQL and Ruby 2. I would suggest you could structure your models like this:

```
class Drink < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :doses, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ingredients, through: :doses
end

class Dose < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :drink
  belongs_to :ingredient
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :doses, dependent: :restrict
  has_many :drinks, through: :doses
end
```

The relationship in Rails follows some conventions:

- Table names are in plural form
- Model names are in singular form
- Foreign keys are named `:othertable_id`
- The model which holds the `belongs_to` relationship also contains the foreign key (in your case this would be `:drink_id` and `:ingredient_id`).
- The `:through` statement generates a join statement in SQL for you, so you can say `my_drink.ingredients` or `my_ingredient.drinks`.
- `dependent: :destroy` will destroy your `:doses` when a drink is deleted, but NOT the `ingredients` linked to it.
- `dependent: :restrict` will deny a deletion of an ingredient, that still is used by one or more doses

I'm always using an extra model for the join table (you could skip that, and rails would do the magic for you). But the big advantage is, that you can store extra attributes into that model, like the amount, unit... And it is also clear in your ruby code, where the relationship comes from.

These models aren't tested, and I'm not 100% sure if the `:through` syntax is correct. But you should get the idea.